# Alternatives Wort für »Kinderschänder«?

Tags: single-word-request, synonym, political-correctness

Ich habe in einem Facebook-Post Folgendes gelesen:

> Bitte von dem Gebrauch des Begriffes "Kinderschänder" absehen, das ist so ein Schlagwort der rechten Rattenfänger. Es ist auch herabwürdigend gegenüber den Betroffenen - ein Missbrauch ist eine Sache, aber eine 'Schande' haftet einem an und impliziert eine mögliche Mitschuld. Der Begriff stammt aus rechtsradikalen Kreisen und wird leider inzwischen manchmal unbedacht aufgegriffen.

1. Dass die »Schande« auf die falsche Seite, die des Opfers, gelegt wird, halte ich für zutreffend und das alleine reicht schon, um sich nach einer Alternative umzusehen, aber stimmt es auch, dass der Begriff aus rechtsradikalen Kreisen stammt?
2. Gibt es irgendwelche Alternativen? Sowohl [Duden](//www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kinderschaender) als auch [Wiktionary](//de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kindersch%C3%A4nder) listen keine Synonyme.

   Mir fallen leider keine ein:

   - *Kinderficker?* Zu derb.
   - *Sexualstraftäter mit minderjährigem Opfer?* Juristische Termini sind zu umständlich für den Alltag.
   - *Pädophile?* Sind in den meisten Fällen keine Straftäter und unser Rechtssystem kennt gottseidank kein Gedankenverbrechen.

Comment: Woher kommt denn die Behautung, dass "Kinderschänder" ein Schlagwort der "rechten Rattenfänger" sei?

Comment: @Robert hatte mich auch gewundert (daher Frage #1), aber Iris hat in ihrer Antwort den Wiki-Artikel verlinkt, der die Zusammenhänge etwas erklärt.

Comment: Dass der Begriff Schande eine mögliche Mitschuld impliziert halte ich für eine unbegründete Behauptung, siehe Leichenschändung, Gräberschändung. Schon die Einschränkung, die durch das *mögliche* vermittelt wird, offenbart den Unsinn der Aussage. Und die Idee, dass die Schande an einer Person anhaftet, erledigt sich dadurch, dass man sie aufgibt. Ich sehe hier einen naiven Wunsch am Werk, die Opfer durch angemessene Sprache heilen zu wollen.

Comment: Außerdem ist die Behauptung, der Begriff stamme von Rechtsradikalen, eine Geschichtsfälschung, wie man mit ([https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kindersch%C3%A4nder&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKindersch%C3%A4nder%3B%2Cc0] NGram) leicht prüfen kann,der man entgegentreten sollte um sie zu stoppen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die entsprechenden Strafgesetzbuchparagraphen haben in Deutschland die Überschriften:

> § 176 StGB: Sexueller Missbrauch von Kindern
> § 176a StGB: Schwerer sexueller Missbrauch von Kindern
> § 176b StGB: Sexueller Missbrauch von Kindern mit Todesfolge

Daraus lässt sich umgekehrt schlussfolgern, dass der Täter, der des sexuellen Missbrauchs schuldig befunden worden ist, *Kindesmissbraucher* (oder *Kindesmissbraucherin* – männliche Täter sind aber bei weitem überwiegend) genannt werden könnte.

Dieses Wort birgt einige Schwierigkeiten. Zum einen wirkt es nicht sonderlich idiomatisch, das könnte allerdings daran liegen, dass es schlicht selten verwendet wird. Zum anderen ist auch der vom StGB gewählte Terminus »Missbrauch« des Öfteren Kritik ausgesetzt. So zum Beispiel im [*Sprachlabor* der *Süddeutschen Zeitung* vom 14. Januar](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/kolumne/sprachlabor-verharmlosung-1.3331571):

> Der unterschwelligen Verharmlosung macht sich nach Meinung unserer Leserin F. schuldig, wer die Dinge, statt sie bei ihrem schlimmen Namen zu nennen, in verhüllende Begriffe packt. Zwei Beispiele […], zweitens den »Missbrauch«, der für Verbrechen aus sexueller und sadistischer Gewalt stehe und fatalerweise so klinge, als gebe es einen sexuellen *Ge*brauch.

Dieser Kritik muss einerseits entgegnet werden, dass Grimms Wörterbuch unter dem Stichwort [*brauchen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/brauchen) auch die Bedeutung *ein Mädchen brauchen* nennt und mit »coire cum puella« erklärt (ebendort). Andererseits darf eine alternative Ansicht, unter anderem von Thomas Fischer vertreten, ins Spiel gebracht werden,

> … wonach der Sexualtäter keine Menschen missbrauche, sondern »seine soziale, physische und psychische Dominanz oder eine bestimmte Zugangsmöglichkeit zu den Kindern oder anderen besonders schutzbedürftigen Personengruppen.« (Sprachlabor)

---

Wie Hubert und du bereits erwähnt haben, bergen die vorgeschlagenen Begriffe *Kinderf…* und *Pädophiler* jeweils eigene Unzulänglichkeiten. So deckt der § 176a StGB ausdrücklich folgenden Fall ab:

> Der sexuelle Missbrauch von Kindern wird in den Fällen des § 176 Abs. 1 und 2 mit Freiheitsstrafe nicht unter zwei Jahren bestraft, wenn
>
> 1. eine Person über achtzehn Jahren mit dem Kind den Beischlaf vollzieht oder ähnliche sexuelle Handlungen an ihm vornimmt oder an sich von ihm vornehmen lässt, die mit einem Eindringen in den Körper verbunden sind,

Nur dieser Fall, und auch nur der erste Teilsatz erlauben es, korrekterweise von einem *Kinderf…* zu sprechen.

Der Begriff »Pädophiler« scheitert sogar aus zwei Gründen: Erstens wird bei weitem nicht jeder Pädophile einschlägig straffällig, zweitens werden diese Verbrechen auch von Nichtpädophilen begangen, zum Beispiel um sich ihrer Macht selbst zu vergewissern.

Answer (score 9):

### schänden

Dieses Verb hat zwei Bedeutungen:

1. Jemandes Ehre durch eine frevelhafte Tat verletzten.

   > Neonazis haben Gräber auf dem jüdischen Friedhof geschändet, indem sie Hakenkreuze auf die Grabsteine gesprüht haben.
2. Jemandem die sexuelle Unschuld rauben.

   > Ich werde nicht zulassen, dass irgend jemand meine Tochter schändet, solange sie unverheiratet ist.

2 hat seinen Ursprung in 1. In früheren Gesellschaften war man der Meinung, dass das Opfer durch die Tat in den Zustand der Schande gebracht wurde. Heute sieht man das anders, aber das ändert nichts daran, dass das Verb »schänden« auch heute noch gebraucht wird, um auszusagen, dass jemandem die sexuelle Unschuld geraubt wurde.

Ein Aspekt hat sich aber dennoch geändert: Heute wird bei der Schändung einer Person davon ausgegangen, dass das a) mit Gewalt und b) gegen den Willen des Opfers geschieht. Früher wurde auch eine freiwillige Teilnahme an einer sexuellen Handlung als Schändung angesehen.

---

### Kinderf...

Wer Kinder schändet, muss nicht unbedingt einen Geschlechtsverkehr vollziehen (das passiert in den meisten Fällen auch gar nicht). Daher ist »Kinderficker« nicht nur derb, sondern inhaltlich auch in den meisten Fällen falsch.

---

### Pädophiler

Wie in der Frage bereits richtig angemerkt wurde, bedeutet der Umstand, dass jemand pädophil ist, nicht dass er tatsächlich sexuelle Handlungen an oder mit Minderjährigen vollzieht. Es bedeutet nur, dass sich jemand sexuell zu Minderjährigen hingezogen fühlt. Das ist aber nicht die Schuld des Pädophilen und natürlich auch kein strafbarer Tatbestand. Die Pädophilen haben sich ihre Neigung ebensowenig ausgesucht wie die Damenwäscheträger, die Schwulen und Lesben oder die Blümchensexliebhaber. Dieser Begriff kommt als Alternative für »Kinderschänder« also nicht in Frage.

---

### Fazit

Ich komme daher zu dem Schluss, dass es derzeit keinen wirklich brauchbaren kurzen Begriff für einen Straftäter gibt, der sich an Kindern vergeht, wenn man das Wort »schänden« vermeiden will.

---

### Nachtrag

Gerne komme ich Jans Anregung nach und ergänze, indem ich einen Teil seines Kommentars zitiere:

> Es gibt durchaus Kinderschänder, die keine pädophile Neigung haben (sondern alleine um sich ihre Macht zu beweisen die Handlungen vollziehen).

Comment: @Hubert wenn man ganz korrekt sein will, kann Kinderschänder (in Bedeutung #2) natürlich auch nicht strikt zutreffend sein, nämlich dann, wenn das Opfer ein bereits sexuell aktiver Teenager ist.

Comment: @FelixDombek Zumindest in Deutschland wird ganz eindeutig in den Rechtsnormen unterschieden zwischen »Missbrauch von Kindern« (unter 14 Jahren) und »Missbrauch von Jugendlichen« (14 bis 18 Jahre). Mir selbst gefällt überhaupt nicht, dass die verurteilten Missbraucher von Jugendlichen inkorrekterweise immer wieder mit »Kinderschänder« betitelt werden. Sprachliche Korrektheit sollte dort kein Luxus sein.

Comment: Sprachliche Korrektheit in juristischen Dingen _ist_ ein Luxus und etwas das auch und gerade die Medien regelmäßig nicht schaffen. Warum sollte das gerade hier anders sein?

Comment: Heute hat sich vor allem die Vorstellung erledigt, dass Frauen als Jungfrau in die Ehe zu gehen haben.

Answer (score 2):

Ich nutze das Wort *Kinderschänder*  nicht, sondern spreche allgemein von *Sexualstraftätern.*

Im [Wikipediaartikel](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindersch%C3%A4nder) zum Begriff *Kinderschänder*  wird außerdem folgender Alternativvorschlag genannt:

> Maria Pober, Vertreterin der feministischen Linguistik, schlägt die – zudem gegenderten – Wörter „mädchen-, frauen-, buben-/jungen- bzw. männervergewaltigerIn“ vor, welche den Täter explizit werden ließen.

aus: Maria Pober: Gendersymmetrie. Überlegungen zur geschlechtersymmetrischen Struktur eines Genderwörterbuches im Deutschen. Königshausen & Neumann, Würzburg 2007,ISBN 978-3-8260-3445-9, S. 173

Comment: Zum Vorschlag von Frau Pober muss angemerkt werden, dass man in der Regel zum Glück *nicht* weiß, ob sich der Täter an einem Mädchen oder Buben vergriffen hat. (Oh, »vergreifen« ist auch noch ein interessant verharmlosendes Wort.)

Comment: Der Wikipedia-Artikel beantwortet sogar die Frage nach dem rechten Hintergrund ganz gut. +1.

Comment: @Jan, das kommt darauf an. Wenn zuerst Kinder verschwinden und überall in den Medien gesucht werden (in Berlin denke ich da sofort an Elias und Mohamed), dann weiß man natürlich das Geschlecht der Opfer und kann den Täter dann auch klar Bubenvergewaltiger nennen.

Comment: Aber »Vergewaltiger« passt auch nicht. Dafür gibt es ja einen eigenen Straftatbestand, der auch zur Anwendung kommt, wenn Kinder vergewaltigt werden. Da würde man den Paragraphen, der sexuelle Handlungen mit Minderjährigen verbietet, ja gar nicht brauchen.

Comment: Als _Kinderschänder_ werden allerdings mitunter auch Leute bezeichnet, die eben – zumindest nach den lokal gültigen Gesetzen – keine Straftat begangen haben und erst recht keiner überführt oder angeklagt wurden.

Answer (score 2):

Praktisch alle umgangs- und fachsprachlichen Begriffe in diesem Bereich bieten verschiedene Angriffsflächen für Kritik, indem sie Details zu Opfer, Täter, Tat, Motiv, Rechtmäßigkeit, Einverständnis etc. andeuten oder aber verstecken. Wie bei nahezu allen Wörtern, insbesondere Komposita und Lehnwörtern, tritt die Kritik aber schnell in die **etymologische Falle**: Sie behauptet eine *innere*, *eigentliche* oder *ursprüngliche* Bedeutung, die in der Sprachpraxis meist gar keine oder kaum eine Rolle spielt. Allerdings kann andauernde oder öffentlichkeitswirksame Kritik das gesellschaftliche Bewusstsein durchaus beeinflussen. 
Das heißt, wenn die im in der Frage zitierten Posting vertretene Ansicht oft genug wiederholt oder von einflussreichen Personen geteilt wird, wird sie letztendlich sprachliche Wirklichkeit, egal wie zutreffend sie anfänglich war. 
Dies trifft in ähnlicher Weise auf Kritik anhand **besetzter Begriffe** zu: Gesellschaftliche Gruppen können u.a. durch vermehrte Verwendung die Deutungshoheit über Wörter bekommen und manche gelangen dadurch sogar in den Status eines *Fahnenwortes*. Dadurch wird im öffentlichen Sprachgebrauch vorangenommen, dass wer bestimmte Worte oder Formulierungen verwendet, einer bestimmten Denkrichtung angehört oder sich ihr anschließen möchte.

Ohne entsprechende Quellenarbeit traue ich mir eine genaue Einschätzung von *Kinderschänder* unter diesen Voraussetzungen nicht zu. Offensichtlich wird aber zumindest in bestimmten („linken“) Kreisen angenommen, dass die Verwendung dieses Begriffs Anzeichen für die Zugehörigkeit zu anderen („rechten“) Kreisen ist, also muss wer zu diesen bestimmten (oder zumindest nicht zu jenen anderen) Kreisen gerechnet werden will entweder auf das Wort gänzlich verzichten oder, was ungleich schwieriger ist, sich aktiv für eine Neubewertung einsetzen, d.h. die Übernahme der Deutungshoheit anstreben.

Somit bleibt erstens der allgemeine Hinweis, dass man die passendste Bezeichnung verwenden sollte, die man vertreten kann, wenn es denn überhaupt nötig ist, anderen Menschen solch einen (und womöglich nur diesen) Stempel aufzudrücken, und zweitens nochmal der spezielle Hinweis, dass es in diesem Fall wohl keine etablierte Bezeichnung gibt, die deutlich weniger angreifbar wäre.

### Postskriptum

Es folgen nachträglich trotzdem ein paar Gedanken zu den Begrifflichkeiten, die helfen könnten, das passende Wort zu (er)finden.

Ein *Peiniger* ist ein Täter, der seinem Opfer i.d.R. unmittelbar körperliche oder seelische Qualen (nicht aber materiellen Schaden) zufügt. Das dürfte in  vielen Fällen zutreffen, ist aber ziemlich unspezifisch.

Beim *Verführen* bleibt kein Zweifel, dass es einen alleinig schuldigen Täter gibt, aber der Aspekt von Zwang oder Machtausnutzung wird durch unterstellte oder zumindest als möglich angenommene Einvernehmlichkeit überlagert. 
Auch wenn sich jemand an einem anderen Menschen *vergeht* oder *vergreift*, ist sie nicht ausgeschlossen, obgleich unwahrscheinlicher.

Bei einer *Vergewaltigung* kann es hingegen keinerlei Einverständnis des Opfers geben, sondern es wird sich wehren (wollen), sofern dazu in der Lage. Allerdings ist solche mit sexuellen Handlungen durchgesetzte Gewalt oft schwierig von mit (nicht unbedingt körperlicher) Gewalt durchgesetzten sexuellen Handlungen, d.h. einer *Nötigung*, zu unterscheiden.

Gegen den eigenen Willen Sex zu haben, fühlt sich für das Opfer sicher schon sehr schlimm an, aber jemandes Willen durch „Sex“ zu brechen, ist (bisher) zurecht eine noch schwerwiegendere Straftat als jemandes Körper zur Befriedigung des eigenen Sexualtriebes zu *missbrauchen*. Der entsprechende Gebrauch anderer Körper ist bspw. im Rahmen der Prostitution oder anderer, d.h. nicht direkt entlohnter gegenseitiger Vorteilsnahme durchaus legal möglich. Ob man hingegen einen Menschen und nicht nur dessen Körper miss- und damit prinzipiell auch ge-brauchen kann, wird oft und nicht grundlos angezweifelt.

Dessen ungeachtet gilt die körperliche Selbstbestimmung, d.h. „Missbrauchte“ entscheiden grundsätzlich selbst, ob sie Opfer sind, während die Gesellschaft über (Straf-)Tat und Täter urteilt. Daher gibt es einerseits täterlose *Schändungen* und andererseits opferlose Sexualverbrechen, bei denen sich letztlich der Täter als Rechtsopfer fühlt, da unser Gesellschaftssystem u.a. auf der Übereinkunft  beruht, dass der Bruch von festgeschriebenen Regeln einheitlich bestraft wird: „Gleiches Recht für alle!“ Neben diesem öffentlichen Recht gibt es aber auch das bürgerliche Zivilrecht, das auf Veranlassung eines Beteiligten die „Wiedergutmachung“ regeln soll, wenn keine außergerichtliche Einigung (etwa auf Basis von Reue und Vergebung, Bezahlung oder beidseitiger Verdrängung) erzielt wird, damit es nicht zu wiederum strafrechtlich relevanten Folgevergehen aus Rache kommt. Wo zwar nicht Eigentum und vielleicht auch weder Körper noch Seele, dafür aber Ehre, Würde, Stolz oder Ansehen beschädigt wurde, ist echte Wiedergutmachung schwierig zu bestimmen und noch schwieriger zu erzwingen.

Comment: Man kann auch den Streit um Deutungshoheit anderen überlassen, reden wie einem der Schnabel gewachsen ist, und sich bei Anfeindungen an die Fakten halten, die da sind, dass das Wort bereits in einem Wörterbuch von 1865 auftaucht. In Zeiten, in denen mehr als jeder zweite ein Smartphone zur Hand hat, um die Angabe sofort zu prüfen halte ich es für dämlich in vorauseilendem Gehorsam aus Angst vor Stigmatisierung sich und anderen Lügen auftischen zu lassen. Oder sagen wir jetzt schon *alternative Sprachwahrheiten*?

Comment: @userunknown Welche Erkenntnis soll es bringen, dass _Kinderschänder_ schon/erst Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts belegt ist?

Comment: @Chrissov: Dass der Begriff nicht aus rechtsradikalen Kreisen stammt.

Comment: @userunknown Diese Erkenntnis nützt aber überhaupt nichts bei der Beurteilung, ob der Begriff **heute** überwiegend oder bevorzugt dort verwendet wird. Sprachsystematisch sind bspw. viele Begriffe auf [Neusprech](http://neusprech.org) kaum zu beanstanden, sprachpraktisch hingegen sehr.

Comment: Wie Du vielleicht zugibst es hier nicht common sense, dass "Kinderschänder" eine Begriff ist, der nur von Rechtsradikalen benutzt wird. Es gibt auch offenbar keinen anderen etablierten Begriff. Es kann sich nur um ein mutwilliges Missverstehen handeln, wenn jemand andere wegen des Sprachgebrauchs als rechtsradikal stigmatisiert. Dieser Stigmatisierung noch nachzuhelfen, in dem man vom Gebrauch des Wortes abrät, halte ich für unverantwortlich. Von solchen Leuten lass ich mir nicht diktieren wie ich zu reden habe, zumal Du Dich ja selbst nicht zu einer Ersatzempfehlung durchringen kannst.

Comment: Außerdem ist es eine ganz unerhebliche Frage, ob rechtsradikale überwiegend diesen Begriff benutzen, wenn Nichtrechtsradikale überwiegend den gleichen Begriff benutzen, wie etwa auch bei Topf, Waffel oder Regen. Und "Stempel aufdrücken" ist auch nur eine von vielen Möglichkeiten, Sprache zu benutzen. Die Verneinung, dass also jemand kein Kinderschänder ist, wird ja mit dem gleichen Wort vorgenommen.

Comment: @userunknown „Hier“ nicht, aber wenn man sich zu bestimmten Kreisen zugehörig zeigen möchte, übernimmt man fast zwangsläufig den entsprechenden Jargon und sei es nur, um sich von anderen Kreisen eindeutig abzugrenzen. Leider werden beide Seiten solche sprachlichen Erkennungszeichen (vgl. _Shibboleth_) auch auf Leute anwenden, die zu keiner von beiden gehören (wollen). Mitunter kommen also auch Neutrale nicht umhin, die den Rechten von den Linken unterstellte Sprache zu vermeiden, nicht um (von beiden Seiten) den Linken, sondern um *nicht* den Rechten zugerechnet zu werden – und andersrum. → PC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52492/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-crissov).

Answer (score 1):

Du kannst *Vergewaltiger* oder genauer *Kindervergewaltiger* als Ersatz nutzen, es klingt nicht so extrem, meint aber gegenüber dem Täter das gleiche ohne auch das Opfer anzugreifen.

Allerdings würde ich heute *Kinderschänder* nicht mehr als wirklich angreifend gegen das Opfer werten, zwar ist es eigentlich im Wort mit inbegriffen, aber wie so oft, hat sich ein Wort der gesellschaftlichen Denkweise angepasst und bedeutet nicht mehr das, was seine Teile eigentlich vermuten lassen.

Dass *Schänder* oder *Kinderschänder* von den „Rechten“ kommt ist nicht falsch aber zu einfach dargestellt.
Wie warscheinlich relativ klar ist, kommt das Wort aus einer Zeit als es noch die „Schande“ der Frau war nicht „unbefleckt“ in die Ehe zu gehen (genau genommen war sehr viel Schande nicht nur Frauen gegenüber). Sicher würden wir die Leute aus dieser Zeit heute als extrem rechts ansehen, allerdings waren sie in ihrer Zeit wohl eher die Mitte.

Comment: Ich glaube, die Kritik ist nicht, dass Kinderschänder von den Nazis kommt, sondern heute vorallem von Nazis verwendet wird. Aus Wikipedia: Die Bezeichnungen finden unter anderem in neonazistischen Kreisen als Schlagwort Verwendung, oft im Zusammenhang mit der Forderung nach „harten“ Strafen für solche Straftaten, etwa Todesstrafe und Zwangskastration. Darüber hinaus finden sie auch in manchen Massenmedien weite Verbreitung.[9]

Comment: Das Stimmt, allerdings ist das mit dem gesamten Bereich so und ich würde auch nicht versuchen dem Problem aus dem Weg zu gehen mit "freundlicher" Sprache, denn das hilft solchen Leuten nur. Und der Ursprung der Wörter und auch der Sprache, nachdem ja gefragt wurde (soweit ich das verstehe) kommt aus einer Zeit lange vor dem 20. Jahrhundert.

Comment: _Schändung_ hat noch nie eine Mitschuld des oder der Geschändeten impliziert. Während im sexuellen Bereich Vergewaltigung, Missbrauch o.ä.  verwendet werden können, scheidet das bei Gegenständen aus: Grabschändung, Leichenschändung, Kirchen-/Tempel-Schändung, Flaggenschändung ... hier gibt es keine wirklichen Alternativen zu _Schändung_, ohne dass deswegen eine Mitschuld eines Dritten behauptet würde.

Comment: @Ingmar Nicht unbedingt eine Mitschuld aber es ist immer auch eine harte Herabsetzung des Geschädigten, "eine Frau wurde geschändet" es ist ihre Schande. "Ein Grab wurde geschändet" das Grab ist in einem schändlichen Zustand. Wobei es gegenüber Frauen durchaus üblich war eine Mitschuld zu unterstellen.

Comment: @Etalia: Aus dem Fakt, dass es früher die übliche Vokabel war und dass früher häufig eine Mitschuld der Frau angenommen wurde kann man aber nicht herleiten, dass das Wort folglich diese Unterstellung von Mitschuld impliziert. Im Zitat der Frage steht auch, dass der Begriff aus rechtsradikalen Kreisen stammt. Fragt sich wie es von da in das Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache von 1865 gekommen ist. Die Quelle wirkt ideologisch motiviert und an Fakten wenig interessiert.

Answer (score -1):

Der Begriff "Kinderschänder" ist ungebräuchlich geworden und wurde durch "Kindesmissbraucher" ersetzt. Am "Kinderschänder" halten aber insbesondere Gruppierungen und Personen, die dem rechtsradikalen Spektrum zuzuordnen sind, fest. Auch "Kindesmissbraucher" ist ein umstrittenes Wort, da sich ein Zusammenhang mit sexuellem Gebrauch herstellen lässt. Und dies als sehr mechanische und menschenunwürdige Sicht auf Sexualität angesehen werden kann. Ähnlich verhält es sich mit "Kinderficker". Wenn jemand Penetrationen als "Ficken" bezeichnet, lässt das Rückschlüsse auf das jeweilige eigene Verhältnis zu sexuellen Aktivitäten zu. Das ist Geschmacks- und damit Privatsache. Menschen die als Kinder entsprechenden Handlungen ausgesetzt waren, könnten sich damit diesen Personen gleichgesetzt fühlen. Wer Wert auf eine würdige Sexualpraxis legt, wird damit nicht einverstanden sein.

Angelika Oetken, Berlin-Köpenick, eine von 9 Millionen Erwachsenen in Deutschland, die in ihrer Kindheit und/oder Jugend Opfer von schwerem sexuellen Missbrauch wurden

Comment: »ist ungebräuchlich geworden« und »wurde durch … ersetzt« kann ich so nicht bestätigen. Ich glaube nicht, dass ich schonmal das Wort »Kindesmissbraucher« gehört habe; es ist mir lediglich als logische Variante vorgekommen, als ich den ursprünglichen Kommentar zur Frage geschrieben habe.

Comment: Von dieser Ersetzung hat Google-NGram noch nichts mitbekommen. Die Antwort kann also nur für eine sehr begrenzte Gruppe oder die allerjüngste Zeit zutreffend sein, was ich durchaus für möglich halte. Dass aber alle anderen entweder Rechtsextreme sind, oder zum Thema schweigen erscheint mir nicht plausibel.